# Proper way to do Tabbed application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to do an app that has a WPF *TabControl* on its main screen, and i'm having a trouble with plan of that. Cause it's only one control, and most of the code will be in *MainWindow* class, so here is my question:

How to properly do tabbed application in C# + WPF? Do like I wrote, most methods in the *MainWindow* class(besides dialogs, etc.) - i'm counting seperate files containing *partial class* as one class still, or is there a other way?

Comment: Follow the MVVM design pattern for the separation of concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your problem domain you could separate your main view to several custom controls, which you place in the tabs.

As Vijay stated, using the MVVM pattern is a viable approach to design the interaction between your UI and the underlying model and avoid cluttering your UI with things that belong to the model or even the viewmodel. Again, depending on your problem domain, you can go either of the two ways

```
 ┌─ MainView (XAML/CodeBehind)
 ├─ MainModel (Code)
 └─ MainViewModel (Code)
```

or

```
┌─ MainView (XAML/CodeBehind)
├──┬ SubView1 (XAML/CodeBehind)
│  ├ SubModel1 (Code)
│  └ SubViewModel1 (Code)
├──┬ SubView2 (XAML/CodeBehind)
.. ├ SubModel2 (Code)
   └ SubViewModel2 (Code)
```

Where the views contain nothing but what's really UI (only XAML at best), the models store the data and the viewmodels define the interaction (usually exposed via `Command` objects) between them and usually hold a reference to the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for managing multiple pages (tabs) I found [this resource](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) really helpful. It's explained well and implements things in such a way that makes editing and adding pages/tabs really easy.

For more info, check out MVVM (or Model-view view-model)

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing one sample code application for you. You can download from the below mentioned link.
I hope this application will solve your problem
@Magiczne

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4bUNjAQRJpWRWdTZjhKcFRsa0U?usp=sharing